# type error in sqlalchemy/flask query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I was wondering if I could get some help on an error I have with an app I am making with Flask-sqlalchemy and a postgres database. I currently have a list of years (ints). the elements of the list depend on the year that the user selects. With the list I make a query below searching for results in my database that have fiscal years matching the years in my list:

```
@main.route('/searchresults')
def yearresults():
    entries = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.fiscalyear.in_(list))
    return render_template('yearsearch.html', entries=entries)
```

When I run this, however, I get

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

The error occurs on the line of the query (db.session.query(Post).filter...)

I know my code works when I query with one specific year, but I'm trying to get it to work with multiple unknowns. I was wondering if anyone sees a solution or a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` in your code is a Python built-in object `list` (type).

Please provide actual list object there.